# What is the correct way to store instance-specific state in MobX

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

let's assume that I have an application state which I store somewhere as observable. But also I have an instance-specific state. By "instance-specific state" I mean, for example, state of a checkbox - for each instance of checkbox it should be a separate state, like this:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
```

**So the question is** - What is the correct way to store such instance-specific state in MobX?

And also - should I at all use MobX to handle such instance-specific state? Or should I use useState instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally fine to store some state locally inside component!

For example, if you have a form with different inputs and checkboxes you can just store all of that data inside component and only update some MobX state after form submit.